# Suppose that corresponding to each point $p$ of a set $X$, there is a family $B_p$ of subset of $X$ satisfying ...

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Suppose that corresponding to each point $p$ of a set $X$, there is a family $B_p$ of subset of $X$ satisfying (NB1), (NB2) and (NB3) above. Then $$T=\{G\subset X: \text{for each }x \in G\text{, there is }B \in B_x\text{ such that }x \in B \subset G\}$$ is a topology on $X$ in which $B_p$ is a neighborhoods base for $p$.

**Proof**

Let $$n_p =\{N\subset X:N\supset B\text{ for some }B \in B_p\}$$ It is easy to see that $n_p$ satisfies (N1), (N2) and (N3) of proposition 6. (N4) follows from (NB3), so that by Proposition 6, the families $n_p$ yield a topology 
$T$ on $X$ in which $n_p$ is the neighborhood system for each $p$. By the construction of $n_p$  from $B_p$ it is clear that the latter is an neighborhood of $p$.

In a space $X$, a set $D\subset X$ is called dense in $X$ if $\mathrm{cl} D=X$. If for a set $D$ in $X$, $\mathrm{cl}  D \neq X$, then $U=X\setminus \mathrm{cl} D$ is a nonempty open set such that $U \cap D = \emptyset$. In oter words, if every nonempty open set $U$ meets $D$, then $D$ is dense in $X$. The converse is clear. Thus we get...

Do you have any answer for this proposition? to make that answer be specific and easy to understand, help me... thank you.

Comment: There is no contex in your question. You simply can't copy random things from a book and expect people can help you without giving any surrounding context. Also, please use TeX: your original setting was even hard to read.

Comment: actually thats true that proposition and proof from topology book, but i dont really understand. because of why i ask here to get the other answer :)

Comment: I see, but no one can read your mind; you should explain what are properties (NB1), (NB2) and (NB3), not to mention Proposition 6 cited in the proof. If you don't want to explain, at least cite the book you are using.

Comment: oke thankyou, i forget to put proposition 6 here. can you help me ms.caligula to proof that proposition ?, I get the proposition from Introduction Topology from JV Deshpande